# Cant use CSS and justify content on react Bootstrap

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

so I'm trying to create my app using react bootstrap and I want to change the backgroundColor to my desired ones + I want to move the link tag to the right side, I believe in normal HTML we can achieve it by typing class="justify-content-end" but I cant find the way to do it. Can anyone help me please ? Thanks before.

Here's my code:

```
import "../styles/Header.css"
import { Navbar, Nav} from "react-bootstrap"

function header() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar bsClass="custom-navbar" expand="lg">
                <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                    <Nav className="justify-content-end">
                        <Nav.Link href="#facilities">Facilities</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link href="#room">Room</Nav.Link>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Navbar>
        </div>
    )
}
```

My Header.css:

```
.custom-navbar{
    background-color: #10255A;
}
```

Comment: Is that a typo error or are you missing closing tag of `<Nav>` ?

Comment: oh I didn't copy the code correctly, there's a closing tag in my code

Answer (score 1):

Currently, flex direction of the `<Nav>` is column which mean you have to use `align-items-end` to move link tags to the right

```
<Nav className="justify-content-end align-items-end">
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-playground-forked-16cq1?file=/src/App.js)